# Alertmanager: send a post request to a specific URL when an alert is fired?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm using alert-manager with Prometheus. Is it possible to send a post request to a specific URL when an alert is fired? I'm currently sharing alerts via email. I want it to hit a certain script or directly send a post HTTP request to the desired URL..

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the Prometheus Alertmanager to use the [webhook_config](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration/#webhook_config), it will send HTTP POST requests containing a JSON payload to the configured endpoint.

See the [alertmanager documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/configuration) for more details.